# Magento: Error while Image upload, Response: Admin Login-Form

Tags: image, magento, upload

The image upload in the Magento backend doesn't work.

The progress bar goes up to 100% and then => error.

The content of the server response: Html from the admin-login-form.

Comment: Can you post the error and the permissions on your upload folder plz?

Comment: MEDIA: drwxrwxr-x 17 www-data www-data 4096 6. Jun 15:15 media 

MEDIA/TMP: drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 6. Jun 15:15 tmp


There is no error-message. After the image is uploaded, the image-area is red. The response of the upload-request: html of the admin-login-form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTPS on backend and https domain is different from HTTP domain, you probably get some errors.
Neither if you are doing right, try to disable the flash uploader.
You can do it with **No Flash Image Uploader** plugin.

Maybe neither if there's no problem on HTTPS you problema could be resolved.

The plugin is available at [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/no-flash-image-uploader.html).

The extension key for Magento Connect 2.0 is

> http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Dull_Uploader

It also works on Magento 1.7.